# Modified By Displayed on Question Screen Instead of User Asking Question?

Tags: feature-request

EDIT: Seems there is a new feature indicating the % of questions where the user accepts answers. My goal was for 'engagement' and not points.

Sorry, but I tend not to answer questions by users with less than 100 points because they don't credit/indicate the correct answer. I would rather see who is asking the question and not the user who either modified or supplied the most recent answer.

I just think asking questions on this site and not taking the time to indicate the correct answer is totally against the purpose of SO. Apparently trust matters.

Maybe I should only answer questions for users with less than 100 points, this way they can't down vote my answer.

Comment: I would answer, but your rep is 1.

Comment: You realize it's not about reputation, but just about answering questions you think are worth answering? Plus even a guru has to start at 1 rep when he joins the site

Comment: I wouldn't have bothered commenting on this, but i couldn't see your rep 'cause the sun was reflecting off my laptop screen. SO should do something about that!

Comment: Just do me a favour: Quit!

Comment: I should have expected programmers to interpret the phrase "... I tend not to" as meaning never.

Comment: Damn programmers...

Comment: @Guinness,  Even if you're only 'tending not to' that's still a problem. SO was built on the principle that programmers could band together to help each other, and it didn't matter that they weren't getting paid. They would just want to answer interesting questions. Your attitude is a slap in the face to the founders of the site and every single user who was a newbie at some point.

Comment: So, if reputation isn't supposed to matter, why do we have it? I may not agree with it, but wanting a little quid pro quo for the effort you put in isn't the worst thing I've ever seen.  I'd prefer that he not tar every new user with the same brush, but that's really his decision, not mine.

Comment: @yshuditelu -- now I can't upvote anything for this guy or your comment's no longer funny.

Answer (score 9):

It should not matter who asked the question, only the quality of the question should count. And, if the question is of poor quality, but you still understand approximately what they want, then you should work to improve the question.

We need to encourage and help new users so that they can contribute more and more over time. 
Any idea that damages new users is something I'm totally against.

Also, it only shows 'modified by' on the "active" view. Because it is showing which questions were modified most recently, it makes the most sense to show you how recently they were modified and also by who.

Comment: Each user still owns their own question. I'm proud of everything I post here, and I want to attach my name to it. If I do repeated stupid things, I would expect people to recognize my *name* and not my *reputation* as being an indication of the quality of my post.

Comment: Sort of like a brand. devinb MEANS quality, wit, and intelligence. Also perfection.

Comment: Don't forget humility!

Comment: @Spencer, my humility does not feel the need to announce itself, it is completely willing to work tirelessly with no awards or recognitions.

Comment: Seems like the new feature to show the percent of answers accepted by person asking questions is a better indicator if they are going to provide more interaction on the site.

Comment: @GoogleUser, I agree. Except that it only indicates whether or not the 'accept' answers, not whether or not they participate.

Answer (score 4):

Wrong attitude, wrong approach.

We are not here to gather reputation (even though an upvote does stroke my ego a tiny bit), we are here to answer questions in order to help others. The change you propose would encourage a behaviour that is not desired by the community, or the creators of SO.

I am in favour of everything that discourage the behaviour you describe .

Comment: I may agree with your reasons, but expecting everyone to share them seems a little extreme.  Lots of people can have lots of different motivations and still have the community be successful.

Comment: @Guiness, thats really your own problem. Thats not how its suppose to work. I use that to see if a question has recieved any new contributions since I last visited or left my own answer, and thats how most people use it as well.

Comment: Jeff mentioned on the podcast a new feature to indicate the % of accepted answers to questions. This was my original goal (to engage with users and not just to get points), but until now, had no mechanism to know this.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort questions by "active", then it will display the most recent answerer/editor on the question list. If you sort by "votes", "hot", or "newest" it should display the original author of the question in the question list.

That said, I think your habit of not answering questions from noobie users is counter to the goals of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your request but not your reason.  I'd prefer the questioner to be shown on the recent questions page just like it is on the other questions pages, but only because I prefer the attribution to go to the actual questioner, not whoever had the last modification of the question's data.  Actually I don't use the recently asked questions (front) page often, but it would be good to have them be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select what questions to answer in that manner, that's your choice. But, I do not believe the system would want to encourage this type of behavior. I would expect the majority of questions are asked by low rep user's and therefore, the system should not discourage answering questions from these users. I don't care either way if they switch what user is shown, but if you're basing the argument for the change on "I don't want to look at questions from user's with less than 100 rep", than I think that goes against what SO is trying to do.

To rephrase my answer a little... I have no issue with you choosing to filter in this way; that is absolutely your choice, and I wouldn't want to dictate your usage of the site. However, I do not believe the system should or will cater to this approach because it is not an approach that will result in the most, best and accurate answers to all programming questions, regardless of level of difficultly.

In response to your comment "I'm not saying I want the credit. It just doesn't help anyone to ask a quesion, get a bunch of answers and not let everyone know which one worked.": I agree this is an issue and it would certainly be more ideal if user's did come back and accept answers. But, that is a large reason why the voting system exists, to provide clues to future viewers as to which answers are the best/most useful. So certainly it is ideal if people select an accepted answer. However, even if the OP never comes back and does their duty, the goal SO is to have canonical answers for all programming related questions. And answering everyone's questions and voting on those answers is how that is done, whether the OP accepts an answer or not.