# Allow voting for new members on their own questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

Users with less than 15 reputation make up about 40% of users on SO.  Users with less than 15 rep cannot vote at all, even on their own questions and thus can only reward a single answerer   - by accepting an answer - even on their own questions.  I propose that all users be able to vote on their own questions.  We've already seen [one case where a user explicitly avoided questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15493/modified-by-displayed-on-question-screen-instead-of-user-asking-question) by users with low reputation.  This would help solve this problem by allowing even new users to acknowledge helpful answers by awarding reputation to all that are helpful.

Comment: tvanfosson: "We've already seen one case where a user explicitly avoided questions by users with reputation = 1." link?

Comment: @Mehrdad -- added link

Answer (score 6):

If a person asks a question with 3 upvotes they will be able to vote on the answers to their questions. If a person asks a question that does not receive upvotes, I'm not sure how important it is for them to be able to upvote. Additionally, it might make it easier to setup shell accounts to gain rep.

Comment: Yes, my concern would be shell accounts. Although it's already exploitable because of the down vote bug. I register an account, ask a question (account has 1 rep). I use my main to down vote, then up vote (1 + 2 + 10 = 13 rep). I use the shell to accept the answer (+2 = 15 rep), I up vote my main account. In a few seconds I gained +25 rep on my main, and now have a shell that can up vote as it wishes.

Comment: +1 Agreed and Agreed. The limit is there for a reason. It also means 40% of users has most likely only asked one question and never returned again.

Comment: However, due to the general lack of question voting as discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/stackoverflow-why-arent-people-rating-questions very few new questions get upvoted.

Comment: @Joel, that question was recently migrated here to meta, but it was originally asked over a year ago. I believe since then the situation has improved some. And regardless, two upvotes is not that many to get on a question or questions and does make it harder (if only slightly) to setup and use shell accounts for the purposes of voting fraud.